# Command to clear all Clipboard history in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, clipboard

I've scavenged the Google for a command to clear all the clipboard history but can't find any command for it, the only command is to clear the top to have it nulled/clean (not the entire clipboard history)

The reason for this is to create a task schedule to clear all the clipboard history when locking the user account.

The closest one is the CMD command:

```
cmd /c echo off | clip
```

But again this one just clear the current copy and paste and puts the recent copy and paste into history, this does **not** clear the clipboard history (at least on the latest Windows 10 patch, 2020-07-07)

So anyone that could help me find a solution for this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can do this by stop and restart Clipboard service:

- In **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**:

```all-bat
for /f tokens^=2* %i in ('sc query^|find "Clipboard"')do >nul cd.|clip & net stop "%i %j" && net start "%i %j"
```

- In **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)** with full path, name and extension:

```all-bat
for /f tokens^=2* %i in ('%__APPDIR__%sc.exe query^|find "Clipboard"')do >nul cd.|%__APPDIR__%clip.exe & %__APPDIR__%net.exe stop "%i %j" && %__APPDIR__%net.exe start "%i %j"
```

- In **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file:

```all-bat
for /f tokens^=2* %%i in ('sc query^|find "Clipboard"')do >nul cd.|clip & net stop "%%i %%j" && net start "%%i %%j"
```

- In **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file with full path, name and extension:

```all-bat
@echo off & title <nul & title .\%~nx0 & %__APPDIR__%mode.com con:cols=75lines=5

for /f tokens^=2* %%i in ('^<con: "%__APPDIR__%sc.exe" query^|find/i "Clipboard"
')do >nul cd.|%__APPDIR__%clip.exe && >nul (%__APPDIR__%net.exe stop "%%i %%j" ^
 && %__APPDIR__%net.exe start "%%i %%j")2>nul && Goto :EOF ||color 4f & Goto :^(

:^(
echo; & <con: echo\Ops! ERROR: Administrator rights are required to run: .\%~nx0
rem/; & <con: echo\Try re-launch it using: 'Run as Administrator' (Context menu)
rem/; & <con: rem/ && "%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /t -1 & color & cls && goto :EOF
```

- In **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**:

```all-bat
Restart-Service -Name "cbdhsvc*" -force
```

**Obs.: 1.** This commands (cmd/bat/ps1) requires administrator rights

**Obs.: 2.** For access to the Clipboard History GUI, use: **<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>**

Note: Thanks to **[@Sathyajith Bhat ♦](https://meta.superuser.com/users/4377/sathyajith-bhat)** for Windows key **[`kbd html tag sources`](https://meta.superuser.com/a/6053/969781)**

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[SC](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html)**

  [√] **[Net](https://ss64.com/nt/net.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[NET START, STOP, PAUSE, CONTINUE - Manage Services](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html)**

  [√] **[Start-Service | refer: `PowerShell`](https://ss64.com/ps/start-service.html)**

  [√] **[Stop-Service | refer: `PowerShell`](https://ss64.com/ps/stop-service.html)**

  [√] **[Restart-Service | refer: `PowerShell`](https://ss64.com/ps/restart-service.html)**