# How to create a task scheduler with the following powershell command (restart the clipboard service)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, clipboard, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

So basically this command needs administrator rights in order to work in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

```
Restart-Service -Name "cbdhsvc*" -force
```

But the question is how can I create this PowerShell file with administrator rights and run it as a task schedule when logging on the **`$env:UserProfile`**?

The thread I made before this was **[command to clear all clipboard history Windows 10 cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/1567067/command-to-clear-all-clipboard-history-windows-10-cmd)** and needed to create a new to get help with this.
Thanks in advance!